# Do methods of default TS/JS Data types trigger detection change when called in HTML template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm refactoring an app where devs used function calls straight in the HTML templating like so :

```
<span>{{'getX()'}}</span>
```

this calls the getX method after each detection change which is very bad performance-wise and I fixed it.

However, what about methods of default data types ?
Will Angular check the result of toLowerCase on strings after every detection change for instance ?

```
<span>{{'myString.toLowerCase()'}}</span>
```

Additionally, will the *get* function of a TS Map object be called after every detection change too ?

```
<span>{{'myTSMap.get('key')'}}</span>
```

If not, is using pipes the best way to solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Try putting a console log statement into the typescript property getter. Short answer is yes, use pipes instead.

Comment: Angular change detector doesn't know to differentiate b/n custom functions and built-in functions. Anything within the interpolation is an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole expression is to be evaluated. There is no difference between your custom function and functions, which are provided by virtual machine (e.g. in browser).

[Documentation says](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation):

> Angular *evaluates all expressions* in double curly braces, converts the expression results to strings, and links them with neighboring literal strings.

(emphasis is mine)

Comment: Thank you, if I understood correctly, it would mean that using property binding property like [class]="myProperty" will always be better performance-wise than using class="{{myProperty}}" even if the value of myProperty will never change ?

Comment: In `[val]="expression"` expression will also be re-evaluated. 

To achieve better performance you may find it useful to tweak change detection strategy: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#usage-notes , https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4